# How use Xidel template for input tag

Tags: xpath, html-content-extraction

I want to get value of  this input:

```
<input type="hidden" value="824" id="book">
```

I can get it with XPath like this :

```
//input[@type="hidden" and @id="book"]/@value
```

but I want to do that with Xidel Templates.
http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:
.\xidel.exe "<input type='hidden' value='824' id='book'>" -e **"<input type='hidden' id='book'>{test:=@value}</input>+"**

It seems to work (works for me under Windows).

Answer (score 1):

The shortest template would be:

```
.\xidel.exe "<input type='hidden' value='824' id='book'>" -e "<input type='hidden' id='book' value='{.}'/>"
```